# How to mark a radio button as checked in Angular with ng-click / ng-change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

http://plnkr.co/edit/rXWUUjLtJi79z2hF1uVX?p=preview

I have a very simple plnkr, basically when the `li` elements are clicked I want the radio buttons checked.

How is this accomplished below? Right now no radio gets selected.

If I remove the ng-click, then the user can just click the radio buttons, but I also want the radio button selected if the user clicks on the text/label inside of the `li` which is why I'm trying to get the `ng-click` on the `li` to work this way.

---

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$rootScope',
                              function($scope,$rootScope) {
                                
  $scope.toggleTags = function(type) {
    console.log(type);
    switch(type) {
      case 'watchlist':
        $scope.watchlist = true;
        $scope.private   = false;
        break;

      case 'private':
        $scope.watchlist = false;
        $scope.private   = true;
        break;
    }
  };
  
}]);
```

```css
body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }

li {
  margin: 10px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">
      
    <ul>
        <li ng-click="toggleTags('watchlist')">
          <input type="radio"
                 name="personalGroup"
                 ng-model="watchlist"
                 ng-change="toggleTags('watchlist')"
                 value="watchlist">
                 My Watchlist
        </li>

        <li ng-click="toggleTags('private')">
          <input type="radio"
                 name="personalGroup"
                 ng-model="private"
                 ng-change="toggleTags('private')"
                 value="private">
                 My Private Tags
        </li>
    </ul>
    
  </body>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/izHQWdgixPx0yRAhv4sT?p=preview

Comment: @K.Toress ah cool that works too :D *+1* and this preserves the use of `ng-click` to capture events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this example I would not use `ng-click` to do this. Instead I would use HTML DOM objects `<label for="radio_button_id_here">`.

HTML

```html
<li>
  <input type="radio" name="personalGroup" ng-model="watchlist" value="watchlist" id="watchlist">
  <label for="watchlist">My Watchlist</label>
</li>

<li>
  <input type="radio" name="personalGroup" ng-model="private" value="private" id="private">
  <label for="private">My Private Tags</label>
</li>
```